# Как вывести значение из ion range slider?

Tags: javascript

```js
$("#range_33").ionRangeSlider({
   type: "single",
      min: 0,
      max: 100000,
      from: 30000,
      from_min: 1000,
      from_max: 150000,
      step: 1000,
  });
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
 <h3>Я хочу получить: тут значение Р</h3>
<div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
 <input id="range_33" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Докопался сам. Ответ:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var $range = $("#range_46"),
            $result = $("#result_46");

        var track = function (data) {
            $result.html(" " + data.from);
        };

        $range.ionRangeSlider({
            type: "single",
            min: 1000,
            max: 99000,
            from: 30000,
            step: 1000,
            onStart: track,
            onChange: track,
            onFinish: track,
            onUpdate: track
        });
    });

<div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h3>Я хочу получить: <span id="result_46"></span> Р</h3>
                    <div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input id="range_46" />
                    </div>
```